# Determine the optimal strategy and maximize the reward

Tags: algorithms, optimization, dynamic-programming

Given an array of length `n` filled with objects which contain 2 ints (`size` and `reward`).

Now 2 players are taking turns, each player has an int value we call `strength`. Let's call them player A and player B, player A goes first.

Player A can pick whichever object from the array he wants and decrease the `size` of the object by his `strength` (`pickedObj.size -= playerA.strength`), he can also skip his turn by simply not picking an object.

Player B is simple minded and for all his turns uses the same greedy strategy: he picks the object with the smallest `size` and decreases it's `size` by his `strength` (`pickedObj.size -= playerB.strength`), player B can't skip turns.

Once a player decreases the `size` of an object to 0 (or bellow) he receives the reward (`playerX.reward += finishedObj.reward`) associated with that object. Each player starts with 0 reward points (`playerX.reward = 0`).

Given an array with `n` objects, player A with `strength = m` and player B with `strength = k`, compute the maximal amount of `reward points` that player A can win.

**Examples:**

Example 1:

```
obj[] array = `{ (9,5), (6,2), (7,3) }`;
playerA.strength = 4;
PlayerB.strength = 5;

int solution = determineMaxReward(array, 4, 5);

// The solution (max amount of money player A can win) is 10.
```

Explanation:

1. Round 1: Player A skips this round, player B picks `arr[1]` and therefore decreases it's `size` by his `strength` (now `arr[1] = (1,2)`).
2. Round 2: Player A picks and finishes `arr[1]` (`playerA.reward += 2`), player B picks `arr[2]` (`arr[2] = (2,3)`)
3. Round 3: Player A picks and finishes `arr[2]` (`playerA.reward += 3`), player B picks `arr[0]` (`arr[0] = (4,5)`)
4. Round 4: Player A picks and finishes `arr[0]` (`playerA.reward += 5`)

That's an optimal game for player A, the at the end he is left with 10 reward points which is the maximal amount of reward points he can possibly achieve.

Example 2:

```
obj[] array = `{ (2,1), (2,5) }`;
playerA.strength = 1;
PlayerB.strength = 2;

int solution = determineMaxReward(array, 1, 2);

// The solution (max amount of money player A can win) is 5.
```

Example 3:

```
obj[] array = `{ (9,3), (10,3), (4,1), (8,1), (9,2) }`;
playerA.strength = 5;
PlayerB.strength = 3;

int solution = determineMaxReward(array, 5, 3);

// The solution (max amount of money player A can win) is 10.
```

**My current unproven (in the sense of optimality) approach:**

For each object, I compute the minimal number of picks player A needs to make in order to finish that object. Then I reduce to the knapsack problem, size of the knapsack being the number of picks player A can do during the game, then the best way to fit the objects with their size and reward into the knapsack (such that the reward is maximized) is found.

Now I'm not sure if this is optimal, I can't find a counterexample where my approach doesn't work but I also can't prove that it's optimal. Any help/comments are appreciated.

This is a problem I have been struggling with for a while now, I encountered it during a programming contest in the context of dynamic programming.

Comment: Can you credit the source of the problem?  In particular, can you edit the question to provide the name of the programming contest, with a link to it (if possible)?  Is the contest still ongoing?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving contest problems for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.  (continued)

Comment: You tagged it with dynamic-programming.  We've written some general reference information on how to approach dynamic programming problems: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info.  I suggest you try working through the systematic approach listed there, step by step, then if you're still stuck, edit the question to show what progress you made and at what point you got stuck.  What possible decomposition into "subproblems" have you tried so far?  Can you write an inefficient (exponential-time) recursive algorithm to solve this?

Comment: @D.W. The contest is long over (it was contest at my school), the problem statement isn't written in english, this post is my translation of it. I encountered the problem in the context of dynamic programming which is why I set it as a tag. Thanks for the additional info!

Comment: Does the problem give ranges for the sizes and strengths?  Because there's many ways this can be optimized, and a purely optimal solution seems really difficult.

Comment: @DanielV all the numbers involved are <= 100, for now I'm fine with ANY algorithm which solves this in non-exponential time. And then from there I would worry about further optimizations.

Comment: @D.W. I edited the question, what do you think of the described approach?

Comment: @AnnaVopureta Can you see how, if the all the sizes are sufficiently large, they don't matter outside a few arithmetic computations?  If you have a board $\{(x, y)\}$ and the strengths are 2,3; then outcome for $x=1000$ is the same as the outcome for $x = 1000000$.

Comment: @DanielV I made the same observation, computing if player A can finish a certain object can be done for fairly large numbers, the problem is deciding on what objects to pick during each turn. See example 2 where player A can't finish any object if we view them seperately.

Comment: @AnnaVopureta If the sizes are sufficiently large, then you don't even need to work out which stacks to decrease.  Order of play becomes of no consequence.

Comment: @DanielV I don't see how "sufficiently large sizes" can make the order of play irrelevant, please be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key observation is that, for player A, picking an object which is not being picked by player B is equivalent to skipping the turn and saving this pick for later (for example use a variable `savedPicks`). Now instead of having to decide upon which object to pick the problem becomes deciding if player A should pick the current object picked by player B or save the pick for later. So we iterate through the objects depending on how player B picks them and either also pick the object as he does or save a pick for later.

Now the problem is solvable with [DP](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/dynamic-programming-from-novice-to-advanced/), observe that your state consists of the current object which is targeted by player B, the remaining size of the object and the number of picks player A has saved.

There are three transitions:

1. Object is finished, move to the next one,
2. Player A skips the round and saves a pick for later (`savedPicks++`),
3. Player A uses a saved pick to pick the current object (potentially getting the reward if his pick finished the current object).

Solve each of the three transitions, apply memoization (save already computed states, use a 3 dimensional array for example), don't forget the base case (all objects have been finished).

Happy coding!